# Mi codigo ignora el ciclo for

Tags: java, netbeans

En netbeans estoy intentando un for anidado y el codigo lo ignora, ya intente con varios tipos de variables, cambiando los parentesis de lugar, etc. Nada funciona, ayuda

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    float N1,N2;
    int i,j;
    try{
        System.out.println("Ingrese un numero del 2 al 5");
        N1=Float.parseFloat(br.readLine());
        System.out.println("Ingrese un numero del 2 al 10");
        N2=Float.parseFloat(br.readLine());
        for (i=1;i==N1;){
            System.out.println("Valor de I="+i);
            for (j=1;j==N2;){
                System.out.println("Valor de J="+j);
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e){}
    
}
```

}

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Si explicas que tratas de hacer, capaz podemos ayudarte... sabes como funciona un for? que hace cada parte? porque tu for, no suena logico.. y si funcionara, nunca terminaria...

Comment: En el bucle for, la posición de en medio de la declaración (En tu caso `i==N1`) es la cláusula que se debe cumplir para *SEGUIR* en el bucle... dado que declaras N1 igual al número introducido por consola, si ese número es diferente a 1 (valor inicial de i) nunca jamás entrará al bucle for, porque esa condición no se cumple ni de inicio... Además si entrase (introduces un 1), el bucle nunca acabaría porque ninguna de las dos variables de la comparación se modifican. Te recomiendo que repases el funcionamiento básico de los bucles. Un saludo :)

Comment: Podrias escribirme el 'for' bien redactado por favor?

Answer (score 2):

un bucle for debe tener esta estructura

```
for (inicializacion; condicion; actualizacion) {
    ...
}
```

debes colocar el codigo de la siguiente forma

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    float N1,N2;
    int i,j;
    try{
        System.out.println("Ingrese un numero del 2 al 5");
        N1=Float.parseFloat(br.readLine());
        System.out.println("Ingrese un numero del 2 al 10");
        N2=Float.parseFloat(br.readLine());
        for (i=1;i<=N1; i++){
            System.out.println("Valor de I="+i);
            for (j=1;j<=N2; j++){
                System.out.println("Valor de J="+j);
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e){}
    
}
```